# Group by weeks and dates EF in descending order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, date, calendar

My query for a list of *dbTable date records* to group by weeks, and `sort the list & nested days in descending date order` is not working. In SO there is a group by week, but not on sorting the both the collection and nested days of the week in descending order.

I have a table like so, with a list of POdateRecordsTable -

```
Id | Date | Week# | PO | ContractorId
```

Given DateTime.Now, and weekStarting on Monday - **how to group/aggregate/sort the records `in descdending order` for the `List of date records by Week`**?, sorting both the out outer weeklist and nesteddayslist in descending order.

---

```
POdateRecordsEntity.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PO == "Unpaid" 
                                    && p.Date <= yourTime).
                      .Select(t => new
  {
      Year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", t.Date ),
      Week = SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww", t.Date ),
      Hours = SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", t.Date )
  })
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Week} );
```

I am *loosing the type & fields* on the returned list. I.e. same type POdateRecordsEntity and *it does not group by weeks since its not a DateTime Extension*

Comment: what is the `SingleOrDefault` for? you only need one records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a list of records that are group by week and each of the list sorted by date in descending order, you can try:

```
POdateRecordsEntity.Where(p => p.PO == "Unpaid" 
                                && p.Date <= yourTime).
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Year, x.Week} )
.toDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Date).toList());
```

Comment: Hi, will the Dictionary contain the strongly type PO records or is it the value object thats the strongly typed, can you include a sample usage snippet on getting the the *typed* recrods. *I am trying to bind this back to a Grid thats thats strongly typed, so should I return to like List.*

Comment: The key of the dictionary is not strongly typed, but the value is a list of strongly typed POdateRecordsEntity. I think this is all you need.

Comment: I didn't actually run the code, you may need to tweak a little bit though. but you get the idea.

Comment: I am tweaking it to run, its not that far off... I have a nested/FK model with `PO Week#` which holds a collection of `PO WeekDays`when I tried to add it its not able to convert. on the Entity - should I change the collection to a dictionary and will that still work with EF if I make that change? or should I change the return to enurmeable or List?

Comment: Add a toList() after the Where clause

Comment: It saying Date.WeeK no extension found? and X.Key or X.Id is not longer found, I also tried to change the  to X.Date and its not finding it, says no extension

Comment: Sorry DateTime doesn't have Wekk property. My bad. Updated. I mean your PoWeek object. However, you shouldn't just use the object to do it, you should get a identifier of the Week object as key, which I don't know what it should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137003/discussion-between-transformer-and-user3682091).